# MaterialButton with image selector on API < 23

Tags: android, material-design

I'm trying to use `MaterialButton` `checkable` with a `drawableTopCompat` so that when I check that `Button` the text and drawable change color.

**I need it to work on API >= 21**

the result I get so far:

[image]

Here is my xml:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_18dp"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextButton.Checkboxed"
    android:text="Test"/>

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_18dp"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextButton.Checkboxed"
    android:text="Test"/>
```

**Selector**

```xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
    />

</selector>
```

I've tried `drawableTint` but even that isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to make it work using only XML with:

```xml
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_favorite"
    android:textColor="@drawable/selector_checkable"
    app:drawableTint="@drawable/selector_checkable"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextButton.Checkboxed"
    android:text="TEST"/>
```

`android:drawableTint` is API > 23 but not `app:drawableTint`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do it programmatically, because as you found out, `drawableTint` is only available for API 23 and above. If you use Kotlin, you can make this extension function:

```kotlin
fun MaterialButton.updateCompoundDrawablesColor() {
    val color = this.textColors.getColorForState(this.drawableState, 0)
    for (drawable in this.compoundDrawables) {
        drawable?.colorFilter = BlendModeColorFilterCompat
                .createBlendModeColorFilterCompat(color, BlendModeCompat.SRC_IN)
    }
}
```

This updates the color filter for every compound drawable using the same color state list as the text. You can use it like this:

```
val btn: MaterialButton = view.findViewById(R.id.btn)
btn.updateCompoundDrawablesColor()
btn.addOnCheckedChangeListener { _, _ ->
    btn.updateCompoundDrawablesColor()
}
```